# Proposal to merge tags [hls] and [http-live-streaming]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I propose a merge of two identical tags. I believe [http-live-streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-live-streaming) is a superior tag name.

[http-live-streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-live-streaming) has roughly double the number that [hls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hls) does, but neither is insignificant.

There was another related meta.stackoverflow post about a tag synonym, see [this link.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170379/add-a-hls-tag-people-keep-auto-completing-to-hlsl) It was closed and I'm uncertain if anything came of it.